# Переотправка сообщения от юзера через бота-Telegram ко мне в чат (python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

есть кнопка под клавой.

```
btn_feedback = types.KeyboardButton(text=' Заказать звонок')
```

есть к ней сообщение.

```
elif message.text == ' Заказать звонок':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите нормер в ,без спец символов пример ниже\n1234567')
```

????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Что писать дальше что бы введенный номер(Юзером), бот прислал мне, это сообщение с номером.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал следующий порядок действий:

1) Получить update от пользователя. Я бы советовал использовать `ConversationHandler` и использовать регулярное выражение, например `\d{10,11}`, чтобы поймать, когда пользователь вводит телефонный номер.

2) Отправить этот `update` лично вам `bot.send_message(message.chat.id)`, где `chat.id` - это ваш диалог с ботом.

Как работать с `ConversationHandler` можно посмотреть в официальной документации и примерах [тут](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples).